# cordova plugin for beacons when Android app is (Background service)closed/killed in ionic2

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic2

Beacon is not working when Android App is Closed or killed in ionic 2 using Cordova plugin. If any one solution for this Let me suggest.

Comment: I have used this plugin https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode and make changes in 
  @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
       // stopService();
       startService();
    }
Now My services are working fine in background-mode.

Comment: App is working in a Background using plugin but i am unable to get Beacon Service alive when i closed the App.